# Open a Web Application through VBA and Click a Button Using Value in a Range of Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Hyperlink ([www.example.com/bridge/app/job?ID=](http://www.example.com/bridge/app/job?ID=)) and I have list of Job ID's (6 digit codes 441256, 324356, 556789..etc) in column A of my worksheet. If I select a particular cell containing Job ID and click any random shortcut key which assigned in macro (example Ctrl+K) the cell value has to replace the part of my hyperlink after "=" and open that hyperlink in default browser.Also runs a short key to open Job ID details and now want to click a button whose ID is variable everytime i open a new job id.

```
Sub OpenMyLink()
 
Dim strURL As String, fixedURL As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim l As IHTMLElement
Dim lo As IHTMLElementCollection
    fixedURL = "https://intra.web.bc/JMS/ejms/bridge/app/job?ID="
    For Each rng In Selection
        strURL = fixedURL & Replace(Replace(rng, "&", "_", 1, 1), "-", "_", 1, 1)
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink strURL
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:6"))
        Application.SendKeys ("^%v")
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))   
Set doc = IE.document
Set lo = doc.getElementsByTagName("button")
If l.getAttribute("class") = "shb-btn" Then
l.Click
End If
Next rng
End Sub
```

```
id="id3b2d" class="shb-btn" href="#" onclick="window.open('example.com/sites/APP2211459/Jobs/515932','_blank'); return false;;return prevent(event);"
```

I am getting the run time error:

> Run-time  error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: id="id3b2d" class="shb-btn" href="#" onclick="window.open('https://example.com/sites/APP2211459/Jobs/515932','_blank'); return false;;return prevent(event);"

Comment: What is the value of `strURL` when it errors? Set a breakpoint (F9) near the top, and then step through it (F8) and check all your variables as it runs. Also, are the values of `l` and `lo` what you expect them to be? It looks like you never set the `l` variable to anything, so that's probably related to the problem.

Comment: I'm not good at VBA...it giving error @ set doc = ie.document you saw my objective can you give me any reference code to click that button ...with using same fixed url and rng and active workbook only ..because navigate.ie doesn't work on my system as internet explorer is obselete

Comment: You also never set the `IE` object to anything. Nothing is going to work if you can't get that set. Have you looked at other tutorials about how to do this?

Comment: Yes i did but, everyone using function ie.navigate which doesn't work for me...I want to use fixedurl and and follow workbook.